# Grouping x axis numbers to reduce crowding

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, grouping

I have the following code:

```
import yfinance as yf
aapl = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
opt = aapl.option_chain('2021-10-08')
opt.calls.set_index('strike', inplace = True)
opt.calls['lastPrice'].plot.bar()
```

It produces :

[image]

Would it be possible to group the numbers so that there are just 4 or 5 labels.

==EDIT==
What i am looking for is a way so that x axis label is not so verbose. Such as in the example below the numbers start from 100 and increase by 5 till 200. I am looking for a way where it only prints 100, 120 ... 200 and not the numbers in the middle. Is there a way where i can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `iloc`:

```
import yfinance as yf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
aapl = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
opt = aapl.option_chain('2021-10-08')
opt.calls.set_index('strike', inplace = True)
opt.calls['lastPrice'].iloc[:5].plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

You can also do a more complex expressions.

For example:

`opt.calls['lastPrice'].iloc[lambda x: x.index % 10 == 0].plot.bar()`

Comment: Thanks but i was looking for the x labels to not be so verbose such that for example it only prints the x labels after every 5. So it wont print every number from 110 to 115 and just print 115. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Slartibartfast This is what it does.
You can do ```opt.calls['lastPrice'].iloc[lambda x: x.index % 5 == 0].plot.bar()``` to jump in 5. or by 20 if you wish ```opt.calls['lastPrice'].iloc[lambda x: x.index % 20 == 0].plot.bar()```

Comment: Thanks David for your response.  With your suggestion `opt.calls['lastPrice'].iloc[lambda x: x.index % 5 == 0].plot.bar()` the number of bars are also reducing. What i was hoping for was the number of bars stay the same just the labels skip every 20